# How to cancel a method from another thread

Tags: c#, winforms, methods

I have a method in the *main thread* which I wish to cancel it from a `BackgroundWorker` *(no matter which line it is)* if a condition is `true`. something like *disposing*.

Currently I have to define a private `bool` and check it before each line in my method.

```
private bool _cancelIt;

private void myLongRunningMethod()
{
  if(_cancelIt) return;
  //some code
  if(_cancelIt) return;
  //some code
  if(_cancelIt) return;
  //some code
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to shut down the method from another thread? Something like

```
myLongRunningMethod.Stop();
```

*It's not a good code if I have to check the condition before each line in a method*

Comment: Run your method in it's own thread, and abort the thread when you want to kill it.  Other than that I can't think of anything.  The need to do this has bad code smell all over it though.  What is this "Long Running Method" and why do you need to do this?

Comment: @Ryios I edited the question. The method is in the main thread. I want to cancel it from a `BackgroundWorker`

Comment: You can't, you would have to abort the main thread, which would kill the app.  The main thread should be reserved for GUI operations only.  All DoWork methods should be off the main thread in a win forms app.

Comment: @Ryios I don't want to kill the main thread. It's just a method which I call in my main thread.

Comment: You want to kill the method.. The only way to do that is to kill the thread it's running in.  Or do what you are doing already.  If you can't kill the thread, then a refactor is probably in order, so that you can kill the thread.

E.g. make that method run in a thread all by itself, and kill that.

Comment: You are doing it fundamentally wrong, your UI thread should *never* be busy in a "long running method".  That freezes the UI and makes your program unresponsive.  About as unresponsive your method now is to attempts by the BGW to stop it.  Simply invert the logic, run the expensive code on a worker.  That's what worker threads were meant to do.

Answer (score 0):

A work around would be to make a DoWork llambda, that listens to cancel.  Something like this:

```
public void DoWork(Action work) {
    if (!canceled) {
        work();
    }
}


DoWork(() => {
   //do something if not cancelled
});

DoWork(() => {
  //do something else if not cancelled
});
```

Comment: This is not much different than what you were doing though.